# Update row in MySQL table with select in set clause

Tags: mysql, sql-update, insert-update

It is easy to insert a row into a MySQL table from another MySQL table:

```
INSERT INTO sometable (SELECT * FROM anothertable WHERE somefield='somevalue')
```

but how do I do this if I want to update instead of insert? I'm looking for something similar to

```
UPDATE sometable SET (SELECT * FROM anothertable WHERE somefield='somevalue')
```

Obviously, this doesn't work. (The structures of sometable and anothertable are identical).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to update rows based specifically on matches of the primary key, then you can use `REPLACE` instead of INSERT.

```
REPLACE INTO sometable SELECT * FROM anothertable WHERE somefield='somevalue';
```

This means when the primary key column from `anothertable` has the same value as the primary key column in `sometable`, then all the other columns returned by the SELECT are used to overwrite those columns in `sometable`.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replace.html

If the row matching is based on something other than primary key, you'll have to use multi-table UPDATE syntax as @John Woo showed.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be what I'm looking for. Will try this now.

Answer (score 3):

you can join both tables, try something like this

```
UPDATE sometable a
       INNER JOIN anotherTable b
           ON a.colname = b.colName
SET    a.val = b.val,
       a.val2 = b.val2
WHERE  b.somefield='somevalue'
```

Comment: Please, note the * (asterisk) in my code. Your example won't work for me.

Comment: Yup, that's clear, John It was just meant as an example to explain what I wanted. If course, I should have thought of REPLACE myself.